# Eclipse CDT using MinGW does not output in console

Tags: eclipse, console, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I have a Windows 7 64-bit PC and I am trying to install a free C++ IDE, so I chose to install Eclipse Helios with CDT.

For g++, make and gdb I installed msys and mingw according to this tutorial:
http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/HowTo:_Install_MSYS_and_MinGW_for_use_with_Eclipse_CDT

The versions are:

- make: GNU make 3.81
- g++: 4.5.0
- gdb: 7.1

So it should be compatible with my 64-bit CPU.

However when I try to run a very simple program with eclipse, I see nothing on the console. The source code is:

```
#include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
    int i;

    cout << "Enter an integer: " << endl;
    cin >> i;
    cout << endl << "i is " << i << endl;

    return 0;
 }
```

The build is fine and when I launch the .exe with command (windows console) the behavior is as expected.
But with the Eclipse console I see nothing with run and with debug the output is just:
"Enter an integer: ", then when I type in a number and hit enter it does nothing.

Does anyone know how to fix this please?

Thanks,

Guillaume

PS: I use the toolchain "Linux GCC", with "MinGW GCC" I have nothing at all in the console.

Comment: Experiencing same issue on Indigo 32-bit; purlogic's solution worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This console bug has been noticed in 64-bit versions of eclipse:

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=197552&start=0&S=2a2b64e1f1404705c0214976bd477428

A workaround is to install the 32-bit eclipse

Comment: Can happen in Indigo 32-bit as well- tries purlogic's solution below.

Answer (score 140):

This worked for me on 64-bit install of Eclipse on Windows 7 using MinGW:

Right-click on your project. Select "Properties".

Select the "Run/Debug Settings" Property on the left of the new window.

In the right window, click on your executable to highlight (ie - Test.exe) and click "Edit".

In the Environment tab, hit "New"

Name: **PATH** 
Value: **Path to your MinGW bin directory**. (For me this was: `C:\devcore\MinGW\bin`)

Click "OK" on all windows to close down.

Try running again, it should print output to the screen.

Comment: Great! How did you find it? Are you the bug creator? :-) It confuses me a lot when in debug mode and command it's fine. +1

Comment: Thanks a lot for finding a solution to this quirk :)

Comment: This should be the correct answer, shouldn't have to re-install eclipse!!

Comment: It worked for me, surprisingly I add already set this PATH variable in the windows environment, but it still didn't work.

Comment: @Ivan: totally agree with you. this should be the correct answer!! worked for me with cygwin as well :)

Comment: I would like to add that what you are essentially doing is adding the bin to the path Eclipse is using. Therefore, by adding `C:\MinGW\bin` to the Path in Windows, it will work for all projects.

Comment: For most people using MinGW the value should be `C:\MinGW\bin` hopefully that helps, if you have this issue please try this answer instead of reinstalling Eclipse for a 32bit one :/ Thanks a lot!

Comment: Would you please explain why is this solution working ? works like a charm

Answer (score 8):

You need to set up linker
I am using MinGW.

Follow below steps.

```
Goto Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Tool Settings (Tab) > MinGW C++ Linker (Option) > Add Command (g++ -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++)   (default command is only g++)
```

Comment: The above step is actually stopping Eclipse from building binary in my case.

Answer (score 7):

purlogic's solution works.
Instead to set that for every project, I found it can be set globally:

In Window -> Preferences-> C/C++ -> Build -> Environment
Add a variable for your compiler. e.g, I added:
MINGW, with value "C:\MinGW\bin"

Comment: I did this, sometime it works, sometime it doesn't. I am using Eclipse Juno.

Comment: so where is purlogic's solution?! can't seem to find it

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem, because of multiple gcc installations on one PC. But [Greg's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5958914/2056545) only worked partly for me.

In my case the flush was not done in the application explicitly. While C++ programs often use `std::cout << ... << std::endl` where the `endl` does a flush, my program used actual C-output such as the usual `printf`. The `printf` could be seen directly when starting the program in the cmd-window. However in eclipse console they were missing. Hence a

```
fflush(stdout);
```

after the `printf` did the thing for me. That could be an issue within the eclipse console implementation. I guess that's why fixing the Path did  not work for some people here.

An alternative solution instead of setting the PATH within the "Run" settings is to start the whole eclipse using a batch file, which looks essentially like this:

```
set PATH=<mymingwlocation>\bin;%PATH%
start <myeclipselocation>\eclipse.exe
```

Then any run configuration would use the correct MingW location by default. That might also fix other problems that could arise from using the wrong gcc.

Comment: fflush(stdout)    ---- Was the key. Worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to execute the eclipse.exe with administrator privileges ?? it worked for me !

Answer (score 1):

Had this issue on 64-/32-bit eclipse Kepler CDT to work on a openCV/wxWidgets tool, Win7, using MinGW to build.

If anyone comes across this while having this issue and are working with openCV you will already know that there are many outdated openCV building/installing instructions all over the internet.

One I had was to go to Build Settings -> Linker -> Miscellaneous and inside of the Linker Flags text entry box, type in 
        `-Wl,--subsystem,windows -mwindows`
However, this disables cout from outputting to a command line terminal in windows.

Doing some more digging this looks intentional, apparently the -mwindows involves directing STDOUT away from a command line specifically to a GUI-like application.

Also, removing `-mwindows` and just leaving in `-Wl,--subsystem,windows` accomplishes the task of redirecting STDOUT anyway away from the command line all the same.

Now mind you, I haven't built up anything yet outside of a hello world program involving wxWidgets and openCV, so I am not at the point of doing a cout into a part of a GUI so I don't know if that functionality would now be broken or if it would print out to the GUI object, as well as a command line terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Add PATH variable (PATH="your MinGW/bin directory path") into your C++ project by Run -> Run Configurations ->in Environment Tab

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Or set the linker option `-static`.
Works for me at least.