# Eclipse CDT Eclipse CDT using MinGW - exe wont run

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I have compiled the following in Eclipse Indigo 32bit using CDT with MinGW on Win7:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443254/eclipse-cdt-using-mingw-does-not-output-in-console) I have set:

In Window -> Preferences-> C/C++ -> Build -> Environment -> Add a variable e.g, I have added: MINGW, with value "C:\MinGW\bin"

When I select the exe in the Debug folder and click run it says:

```
Launch failed: binary not found
```

When I attempt to run it from outside eclipse I get:

```
Windows cannot access the specified device, path or file. You may not have appropriate permissions to access the item.
```

Even tried running as Administrator.

When I attempt to compile on the command line:

```
g++ -o hello.exe hello.cpp
```

I get:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c:(.tex
t+0xd2): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work if you build from the command line outside of Eclipse: `g++ -o hello.exe hello.cpp`?  If that works, then post whatever command line for GCC that's in the Eclipse build logs.

Comment: Are you using the command line I suggested in the comment?  MinGW should not be looking for `WinMain` unless you pass the `-mwindows` option to the compiler - which you shouldn't do for this 'hello world' console program.

Comment: Seems, you have broken mingw distribution. Try to reinstall with msys (and don't install mingw to windows system directories). g++ hello.cpp should be executing without any errors.

Comment: You were absolutely correct @Torsten. Got the latest version and it build fine using CDT. Many thanks!