# Eclipse After Running the file

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Whenever i run Hello World Using C programming and Eclipse it shows Console as blank White, and the only method for me to view an output on a console is to click the red button "Terminate button" and it will show the output on console.

Is there a way to fix this, whenever we click run it will run the program and show the output on the console without having to click the terminate button?

Thank you very much.

Comment: can you show your code

Comment: Which toolchain are you using (like g++ or MingW)?

Comment: You shouldn't use Eclipse for C language. More seriously, can you show us your code ? Are you sure you are printing a '\n' at the end of the line ?

Comment: Yes sir, Using minGW , downloaded it and it is recognized by eclipse, i'm wondering how to post the code here, it's not letting me   inder 4 spaces for the syntax to be distinguish...

any suggestion for C Compiler IDE? Thanks :)

Comment: Its strange that you have to press the terminate button - this indicates that the application is actually running, but anyway: have you made sure that the PATH environment variable is properly set up? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443254/eclipse-cdt-using-mingw-does-not-output-in-console

Comment: Yes Sir
PATH
C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin

Comment: @user2474851: To indent, either do it in a text editor outside of the web page or paste the code, select it and click on `{}` above the web editor to turn it into indented code.

Comment: i switched IDE using C Pelles C... YAY! it works perfectly. However i can't use getch()... i wonder why...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you mean by "it shows blank white" as if it is closed quickly or hangs ?

but try adding

```
fflush(stdout);
while ( getch() != '\n' )
```

after your printf statement

Comment: whenever i click on build, and then click run, the console shows blank page. Blank White page (background), i have to click the terminate button on the console (red square button) to show the output.

Comment: i switched IDE using C Pelles C... YAY! it works perfectly. However i can't use getch()... i wonder why...

Answer (score -1):

As you can press the red "Terminate" button, your program can be started but hangs and never terminates by itself. We will need to see the source code of your program to tell you why.

Also, don't forget to add `\n` at the end of your `printf()` string or force a flush of the output with `fflush(stdout);`