# Eclipse CDT with MinGW on Windows7 64bit - Debug configuration crashes [maybe solved, still curious]

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows-7, crash, mingw

First of all, I may have found a solution, but(!) I have no idea why it works. So I hope someone can explain what happens and maybe point out a better / right solution. Also, this might help somebody else.

I have Windows 7 64bit OS with Eclipse Kepler 64bit, java version 1.7.0_25 64bit (via jre-7u25-windows-x64.exe) and the latest (don't know how to find out which one exactly)  mingw version (via mingw-get-inst-20120426.exe) installed today.

I tried to run the standard Hello World Eclipse Example Project:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main() {
        cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
        return 0;
    }
```

The release configuration works just fine. However, the debug configuration crashes. The only error message I get is from Windows, saying something like "test.exe does not work any more" (german error message "test.exe funktioniert nicht mehr") - without any further information.

Because a google search only found the reverse case - debug works, release crashes - I got desparate and just tried various fixes for other problems. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443254/eclipse-cdt-using-mingw-does-not-output-in-console) helped, here is a copy of the relevant part:

> Right-click on your project. Select "Properties".
>   Select the "Run/Debug Settings" Property on the left of the new window.
>   In the right window, click on your executable to highlight (ie - Test.exe) and click "Edit".
>   In the Environment tab, hit "New"
>   Name: PATH
>   Value: Path to your MinGW bin directory. (For me this was: C:\devcore\MinGW\bin)
>   Click "OK" on all windows to close down.

With this I can run the Hello World Example in both debug and release configuration. I have however not yet tried a more complicated program, so I am not sure wheter this will really solve the problem.

If you need any further information, please feel free to ask.

Edit:
1) I forgot to mention that I added the mingw\bin folder to the "path"-system variable.
2) I tried adding the "Name:path, value:...\mingw\bin" to Preferences->C/C++->Build->Environment->Add instead. This did not help.

Edit2:
Is the following correct?
The program needs some mingw-dll at runtime. For the release configuration this is directly linked into the .exe, but for the debug release I need to specify where Eclipse can find minGW - and I need to specify at exactly that place because the other option I tried is only used during compilation.
*If so, why does eclipse not do this on its own?* After all, it is only the hello world example and I know that I didn't need to do this in the past.

Comment: Sounds like you were missing a dll required to run the program that is in the directory you added to the path.

Comment: But why does the problem only occur in the debug configuration? Btw, I have the mingw\bin folder added to the path variable. I should probably add that to the Question.

Comment: The debug version may require different dll files than the release version.  Based on the solution you quoted it sounds like when you're running from Eclipse it may use a different environment than if you ran it outside Eclipse, so your path might not be used.

Comment: when I run the .exe outside Eclipse I get exactly the same results - the release configuration  works, the debug configuration (without the change) does not.

Comment: Can you show the compile and link commands eclipsed used to build your project? That will more than likely hint at what the real problem is.

Comment: where do I find those?

Comment: @greatwolf: I think I found it:  

g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\test.o" "..\\src\\test.cpp" and  g++ -o test.exe "src\\test.o"

Comment: @Belga Try passing the switch `-static-libgcc` and `-static-libstdc++` for the second command.

Comment: Where can I change that? I found the above information in a log-file.

Comment: @Belga Eclipse should have a way to add options and switches in the project somewhere for a given configuration.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. I decided to not spend any more time figuring this out. I don't completely understand what was wrong but I am glad that it now works.

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in the comments. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> I think I found it:
>
> ```
> g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\test.o" "..\\src\\test.cpp" and g++ -o test.exe "src\\test.o"
> ```

@Belga wrote:

> Try passing the switch `-static-libgcc` and `-static-libstdc++` for the second command.
>
> Eclipse should have a way to add options and switches in the project somewhere for a given configuration.