# unable to see the output of c++ program in the console

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw

I have installed the eclipse ide(cdt) on my windows 8 laptop and tried writing a simple c program to check whether the program executes.

It did not execute and gave the error : `binary not found` .

So I did some searching online and realized that my system did not have a c/c++ compiler installed.
So I installed MinGW and selected the c and c++ compilers during installation.
Then I set the PATH environment variable to C:\MinGW.
I reopened eclipse, wrote a simple c program and it worked as expected!

I created a c++ project, wrote a simple piece of code and could not see the output in the console!

Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"sample text";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: figured it out:Goto Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Tool Settings (Tab) > MinGW C++ Linker (Option) > Add Command (g++ -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++)   (default command is only g++)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Linker (Option) > Add Command (g++ -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++)*

This is not the right solution.

You have in your path environment variable only `c:\minGW` .
But it should be `c:\minGW;c:\minGW\bin` . (Set the PATH before open eclipse)

Therefore, `libstdc++-6.dll` needed by the current program, can not be found.

**In eclipse there is no error, but no output in the console !!**

It to compile into the program may be regarded as a trick, but **will only work for the standard libs** .

---

your linker flags should not be set like :

--> MinGW C++ Linker (Option) > Command (g++ -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++)

should be set here :

[image]

---

I know in this case it is not necessary at the end `<< endl` to write.
A good programming style should use `<< endl` :

```
cout << "sample text" << endl;
```

Comment: i followed what you explained above and it works. but can you explain the difference between the two solutions. and why did you say my first solution works only with standard libraries? just curious...

Comment: and how come the c program's output was visible in the console and not the c++ program's?

Comment: c programs are not linked to `libstdc++-6.dll`

Comment: your first solution works only with standard libraries. `libstdc++-6.dll` belongs to the standard libraries and will linked with `-static-libstc++` direct into your .exe , so `libstdc++-6.dll` is not needed to run.

Comment: i just realized that after i implemented the changes u mentioned, c++ programs work perfectly but now i cannot see the output for c programs. very unusual behaviour. i am guessing i need to change the linker in the c project's properties. can you give me the linker i need to add.

Comment: @just_a_coder : Try it without any linker options. If that not works ask a new question with code and settings.

Comment: i was going through some other questions on this topic and one of the suggestions was to set the linker to -static. this worked for me. i can execute c and c++ programs. can you tell me the implications of this solution.

Comment: I can not see your .c code . It seems to me your are using the same c++ code. (can not compiled with gcc) I test pure c : `#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
 printf("!!!Hello World!!!");
 return 0;
}`  worked without static

Comment: i tested pure c without -static and it does not show the output. with static and it works!!! i used pure c, the same code you typed above. just wondering about the implications of this...

Comment: compile without -static and look at .exe file with a `Dependency Walker` there are only `Kernel32.dll, Msvcrt.dll, Ntdll.dll`

Comment: @just_a_coder : You wrote in your Question : `I reopened eclipse, wrote a simple c program and it worked as expected! ... I created a c++ project ... no output,` . Now you tell us a `simple c program` also not working ` ??? So what of the two is correct ?

Comment: Note that it is possible to solve the problem with one linker option: "-static".  I do not think the other two are needed.

Comment: @Willem : This can be I have not tested myself so.

Answer (score 1):

You may simply need to flush the output, using `flush` or `endl`. Try this:

```
cout<<"sample text" << endl;
```

or

```
cout<<"sample text" << flush;
```

Comment: it is not always required.There seems to be some other issue

Comment: If you use 64-bit versions of eclipse, there may be a bug there see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443254/eclipse-cdt-using-mingw-does-not-output-in-console)