# No output in c++-program if object is instantiated using Eclipse

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, mingw

I got an issue after installing Eclipse Kepler on my Windows 7 32bit machine. I installed the CDT and the MinGW-compiler. I configured the installation by adding MinGW to the PATH and tested my configuration with a "Hello world"-program, which worked.

The strange thing is, that if I instantiate an object, nothing is outputted. It doesn't matter if it's a std::string or a custom made class. If I instantiate it, nothing is outputted, even if it should be outputted before the instantiation. The exact same code works fine, if I compile it with cygwin gcc from command line. If I change the toolchain to cygwin gcc nothing changes (I've rebuild the program with "build all").

There is no error displayed and no problem listed.

Here's the minimal working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class SayWorld{
public:
    SayWorld(){
        cout << "World!" << endl;
     }
};

int main() {
    //Only gets outputted, if the lines, that don't work are commented out:
    cout << "Hello ";

//  Works:
    cout << "World!" << endl;

//  Doesn't work:
//  SayWorld sw;

//  Also doesn't work:
//  string str("World!");
//  cout << str << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Edit 2:
I narrowed the error to MinGW, as this picture of a Cygwin-Bash-Terminal demonstrates. (The file was not changed beetween the to g++ calls and contains the example above)

[image]

Edit 1 (Legacy)
Toolchain-picture:
-picture removed- (don't think it was necessary)

Comment: please do a full rebuild to make sure you're not working with stale binaries. Because here this works without problems, see also: http://ideone.com/fVfCCO

Comment: As I wrote: for me it also works fine, when I build it from command line. And I rebuild it multiple times with "build all", clean and I even tried manually deleting the .exe... Didn't help :-(

Comment: "If I change the toolchain to cygwin gcc nothing changes" that is very weird - it shouldn't even compile then, as std::string is not in c. are you sure you're not running another binary, maybe from another project?

Comment: @RandolphCarter: I added a picture. Eclipse seems to use Cygwin GCC only as title. Of course it still uses g++ for compiling my code, else you would definitively be right. (Errors are marked as usual in the editor...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reinstalling eclipse and MinGW again, step-by-step following this video tutorial:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=77xZOT3xer4

and having the same problem afterwards, I stumbled uppon this post in the eclipse forum:

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/u/104305/

which has brought me to this solution:

Right-click Project -> Properties -> Run/Debug Settings
Choose executable and hit the "New"-button.
Go to the Environment-Tab and create a new variable named PATH with the value: "C:\MinGW\bin".

As I am no expert, I can't explain to you why it works, but it worked for me. If someone knows, how to do this better or wholly avoid this problem, I'd be glad to listen.

This entry was definitively in my Windows-PATH...

PS.: The problem seems also to be known here:
[unable to see the output of c++ program in the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169347/unable-to-see-the-output-of-c-program-in-the-console?rq=1)