# c++ files compile with mingw doesn't print hello world

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw

I am trying to compile c++ files with mingw and eclipse, **C programs compile and print**, my problem is with c++, I added paths to all the needed files and especially to:

```
C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++
```

where the `iostream` file is located.

The program compiles just fine and runs but it doesnt print the `"!!!Hello World!!!"` message. The code is the ordinary hello world example.

I tried all the includes I could find but nothing seem to help.

Any suggestions?

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
 cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
 return 0;
}
```

EDIT: in my case the answer was found in [Eclipse CDT using MinGW does not output in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443254/eclipse-cdt-using-mingw-does-not-output-in-console)

Comment: It maybe the case that it's printing but it's closing before you can even see it. Try a `cin` right after the `cout`.

Comment: You can also run it from the command line, that should show the message.

Comment: it should print inside the eclipses console so i should see it. and i dont want to run it from the command line i want it to work from the eclipse the same as in the c program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this line `C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++` it seems you are using the 32 bit version of the compiler. There are issues with Eclipse CDT and C++ compiler when their architectures mismatch. Please see which architecture of Java, JDK, Eclipse CDT are you using. If you are going to stick to the 32 bit compiler. Follow these steps:

Uninstall

- Remove all traces of Eclipse (64-bit).
- Remove all traces of MinGW (and/or Cygwin).
- Remove all traces of Java (SDK and JRE).

Restart PC

Install

- Installed latest Java JDK (includes the JRE) 32-bit.
- Installed Eclipse IDE (Java Edition) 32-bit.
- Installed MinGW (with Msys).
- Installed the necessary CDT tools from within Eclipse.

Or you can simply stick to all 64 bit versions but always ensure all their architectures match. For more info, use [this](http://max.berger.name/howto/cdt/) link.

Comment: that you for the answer, is it possible that it will work find on C and cause problems with c++?

Comment: Yes, the C compiler works fine on some cases. But C++ causes problems. This was also addressed in Eclipse forums too. Loot at this question and the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443254/eclipse-cdt-using-mingw-does-not-output-in-console