# Executing std::cout doesn't print in running mode , but does in debugging mode

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, mingw

This is very weird , given this code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "DummySubject.h"
#include "Shop.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "1234567" << std::endl;
    // more code 
    return 0;
}
```

This code doesn't print anything on the console when I execute it in running mode , however when I execute it in a debugging mode , `cout` prints `1234567` on the screen .

Any idea what the problem might be ?

I even used `std::flush` but it didn't help .

Edit :

Without the includes :

```
#include <iostream>
//#include "DummySubject.h"
//#include "Shop.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "1234567" << std::endl;

//  DummySubject mySubject;
//
//    // We have four shops wanting to keep updated price set by mySubject owner
//    Shop shop1("Shop 1");
//    Shop shop2("Shop 2");
//
//    mySubject.Attach(&shop1);
//    mySubject.Attach(&shop2);
//
//    //Now lets try changing the products price, this should update the shops automatically
//    mySubject.ChangePrice(23.0f);
//
//    //Now shop2 is not interested in new prices so they unsubscribe
//    mySubject.Detach(&shop2);
//
//    //Now lets try changing the products price again
//    mySubject.ChangePrice(26.0f);


    return 0;
}
```

Still doesn't work .

Comment: If you drop the the two includes after `iostream` does it work then?

Comment: Check if either "DummySubject.h" or "Shop.h" do something strange.

Comment: @TommyA: Didn't help , check out the revised code , thanks .

Comment: @101010: Didn't help , see edit , thanks .

Comment: What's the compiler you're using?

Comment: @ron are you using the console in Eclipse?

Comment: @TommyA: Yes  , why ?

Comment: @ron http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443254/eclipse-cdt-using-mingw-does-not-output-in-console could be related.

Comment: Honestly I suspect that there is different configurations for debug and release in Eclipse, and that these might be set up differently.

Comment: @TommyA : Yeap , check out my answer , which is taken from the link you provided , thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer :

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443254/eclipse-cdt-using-mingw-does-not-output-in-console)

> This worked for me on 64-bit install of Eclipse on Windows 7 using
>   MinGW:
>
> Right-click on your project. Select "Properties".
>
> Select the "Run/Debug Settings" Property on the left of the new
>   window.
>
> In the right window, click on your executable to highlight (ie -
>   Test.exe) and click "Edit".
>
> In the Environment tab, hit "New"
>
> Name: PATH  Value: Path to your MinGW bin directory. (For me this was:
>   C:\devcore\MinGW\bin)
>
> Click "OK" on all windows to close down.
>
> Try running again, it should print output to the screen.